# Silverstripe form image validation after submit failed

Tags: php, forms, image, silverstripe

I have a little problem to handle the validate of an image after a form submit. There is my form submit function :

```
public function FormAjouterSubmit($data, $form) {

    ....

    Session::clear("PageAuteur.FormAjouterSubmit");

    $texte = "Veuillez remplir ce champ";

    if (!$data['ImageID']) {
        Session::set("PageAuteur. FormAjouterSubmit", $data);
        $form->addErrorMessage('Image', $texte, 'bad');
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }   

    ....

}
```

I have tried !$data['ImageID'] and !$data['Image'] and the form return back and clear my session data. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `RequiredFields` validator? It's usually bad practice to build validation into the submit function.

Comment: Yes. it's to create custom error message below each fields with a up arrow image to point a field.

Comment: That's what `RequiredFields` should do already… how it looks (eg. up arrow) can easily be achieved via CSS. If you need further customization, just subclass `RequiredFields`?

Comment: Can you post an example with a custom error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RequiredFields`](https://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-RequiredFields.html) to validate required form-fields.
The `Form` constructor takes a fifth parameter, where you can supply the required fields validator.

Example:

```
$form = Form::create(
    $this, 
    'FormAjouter', 
     $fields, 
     $actions, 
     RequiredFields::create(['Image'])
);
```

The easiest way to customize the validation message is to use `i18n`. If your default locale is french, crate a file named `mysite/lang/fr.yml` where you can put something like this:

```
Form:
  FIELDISREQUIRED: 'Veuillez remplir le champ {name}'
```

`{name}` will be substituted with your actual field title. Of course you can also omit the placeholder.

If you need different text for individual form-fields, you can use `setCustomValidationMessage` on each field that requires a custom error message.

Example:

```
$uploadField = FileField::create('Image');
$uploadField->setCustomValidationMessage('Please upload a file');
```

Comment: Nice! I'd never use setCustomValidationMessage. I will remove my code and use yours. It's works great it's time to update all my code everywhere! Thanks @bummack.

Comment: This is strange, the custom validation message works for Image, but not on other fields like TextField. It appear a HTML5 styled popup written «Please fill out this fields».

Comment: @StefGuev That's just the basic HTML5 validation. It happens before your data gets sent to the server (purely in the browser)

Comment: Is it possible to do validation after submit with setcustomvalidation message? Actually, only ImageField seem to work this way...

Comment: Look up HTML5 validation. You can disable it by removing the `required` attribute on individual fields. Or by just adding `novalidate="novalidate"` to the form element. Eg. `$form->setAttribute('novalidate', 'novalidate');`

Comment: Thanks @bummzack! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Another problem with this validation... when the submit is redirecting back, all changes made on other fields are not updated when a requiredfield is missing. All variables are reloaded with $form->loadDataFrom( $data );

Comment: If that's the case, you're doing something wrong. Your form should never reach your submit function and redirect back… validation happens before that and will not trigger the submit function if the data is invalid… the data that was entered will not disappear if you set up validation correctly.

Comment: I have verified and as you say, when I click Submit button from my form, it's not submit from my button but from the validation process of requiredfields. So when I'm using $form->loadDataFrom( $data ); into my update form, if a fields is missing, the validation redirect me back with the error message bellow the required field, but reload the $data... It not remember last changes into other filelds... Very Strange